# Implement Neighbors to find the d-neighborhood of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, design-patterns

Input: A string Pattern and an integer d.
 Output: The collection of strings Neighbors(Pattern, d).

Sample Input:
ACG
1

Sample Output:
TCG
ACG
GCG
CCG
ACA
ACT
AGG
AAG
ATG
ACC

What is the algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: Add more information (what is a "neighbor"?, etc.), and show us what you did so far.

Comment: "What is the algorithm to solve this problem??" <- What problem?

Comment: It looks like it's operating on genetic codons, and the goal is to find all codons that differ in exactly `d` amino acids.

Comment: @TomKarzes: You mean "bases"? ;)

Comment: @Pier Actually I should have said nucleotides.

Comment: Sorry, I should make it clearer. It is for DNA sequence so d means how many different bases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
chars = "ACGT"

def neighbors(pattern, d):
    assert(d <= len(pattern))

    if d == 0:
        return [pattern]

    r2 = neighbors(pattern[1:], d-1)
    r = [c + r3 for r3 in r2 for c in chars if c != pattern[0]]

    if (d < len(pattern)):
        r2 = neighbors(pattern[1:], d)
        r += [pattern[0] + r3 for r3 in r2]

    return r
```

Here's some sample output:

```
>>> neighbors("ACG", 1)
['CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACT']
```

Note that this gives neighbors that differ in *exactly* `d` places, as opposed to *at most* `d` places.  If you want the latter (as your sample output suggests), you can simply combine the results for the different values of `d`, as follows:

```
def neighbors2(pattern, d):
    return sum([neighbors(pattern, d2) for d2 in range(d + 1)], [])
```

Here's some sample output:

```
>>> neighbors2("ACG", 1)
['ACG', 'CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACT']
```

Comment: I don't understand what does a r2 mean in the code?

Comment: I used `r2` as a temporary variable to hold the results of the recursive invocations.  There are two cases:  (1) varying `d-1` entries in the tail, then varying the first entry upon return, and (2) varying `d` entries in the tail, if the tail of the string is long enough.  The results of the recursive calls are then adjusted at the top level to create the new entries in the result list `r`.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question, for ACG and 1 example, 'r2 =     neighbors(pattern[1:], d-1), r = [c + r3 for r3 in r2 for c in chars if c != pattern[0]]'. Does r3 = r2 equals CG since d-1=0 no change of the nucleotide? @ Tom Karzes

Comment: @nosense In the case you mention, from the example, `pattern` is `ACG` so `pattern[1:]` is `"CG"` and `d-1` is `0`.  So the return value from the recursive calls is just a list with the single string in it, i.e. `r2` is `["CG"]` in that case.  Then in the following statement, `r3` takes on the single value from the list, i.e. `"CG"`.  The only difference is that `r2` is a list with a single element, and `r3` takes on the value of that element.

Comment: @ Tom Karzes Now I understand how the 'ACG', 'CCG', 'GCG', 'TCG', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'ATG' come from. If I understand correctly, the last round is G replaced with A, C or T and then the pattern[0] = C (at this time the pattern is CG) so we got CA, CC or CT by  r += [pattern[0] + r3 for r3 in r2]. I am curious about how does the first A added to CA, CC or CT?

Comment: It's right here:  `r += [pattern[0] + r3 for r3 in r2]`  This adds all of the cases where the first character is unchanged.  It's just `pattern[0]`, the first character in `pattern`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102131/discussion-between-nosense-and-tom-karzes).

Comment: That is so slick. Thank you for introducing me to recursive functions